# Динамически менять viewport для выбора мобильной/полной версии

Tags: html, мобильная-разработка, viewport

Делаю мобильную версию. Есть проблема зума. На мобильной версии есть тег:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320" id="mobile">
```

По кнопке перехода пишется сессия и вместо этого тега пишется другой:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

Проблема в том что браузер "помнит" ширину в `320px` и применяет его, `initial-scale=1` при этом игнорируется.

Если указать `user-scalable=no`, то масштабируется всё правильно, но увеличить пользователь уже не может. Такой же эффект если поставить `minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1`. А надо чтобы пользователь мог увеличить части страницы.

Как этого добиться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте добавлять этот тег динамически при загрузке страницы

```
var viewPort = document.createElement('meta');
viewPort.name = "viewport";
viewPort.content = "width=1024";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewPort);
```

Либо менять его же:

```
document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]")
    .setAttribute("content", "width=1024");
```

Если это не поможет, то может быть так что [в вашем браузере в принципе нельзя этого сделать - проблема известная](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2011/06/dynamically_cha.html).

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать менять содержимое мета-тега уже после того, как зум стал таким, каким нужно.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var viewport = document.getElementById('desktop');
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=1024');
  }, 500);
};
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024; user-scalable=none" id="desktop" />
```

Comment: не помогло. упирается в `user-scalable=none` , оно запрещает ресайзить, хоть вместе с этим и ставится нормальный масштаб(да и атрибуты непричём, ширина контента понимается нормально), но возможность ресайзить нужна

Comment: но ведь при помощи этого кода атрибут `content` меняется с `width=1024; user-scalable=none` на `width=1024`. по крайней мере, если запустить код здесь, то это работает именно так.

Comment: а, понял логику. но она тоже не работает, я и это пробовал, сделал умозаключение что браузер, судя по всему, берёт настройки тега и всё, хоть удали его(что я и делал) - ничего не изменится.